# object User extends Magic[User]().using("users") can not compiled

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

When using Anorm I want to use a different table name for the User case class:

```
object User extends Magic[User]().using("users")
```

But I get the following compilation error:

**The file /app/models/User.scala could not be compiled. Error raised is : ';' expected but '.' found.**

**object User extends MagicUser↓.using("users")**

Is this a bug of Anorm?

Answer (score 4):

Clearly not a bug, your code is not valid scala. You could do that instead :

```
lazy val User = new Magic[User].using("users")
```

(the convention would be lowercase "user", capital left so that it is equivalent to your intended code)

object is a declaration, not an expression. An object declaration  is

```
object ObjectName extends Ancestor(ancestor_constructor_arguments) {
  // body: data, method and initialization code
}
```

with most parts optional.

You have to do your adaptation either through constructor arguments or initialization code in the body of the object.

As you add no behavior to class Magic, there seems to be no need to declare an object anyway.

Comment: Maybe the play scala documentation http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9.1/anorm#AddingsomeMagicT has error. But my User object should be a companion object of the case class User, otherwise the lazy val User must be put in a package object? Are there any more elegant solutions?

Comment: If you need it to be an object, you must go through constructor or initialization code. Method using return a new instance,so it is likely Magic is immutable so that it may be fully initialized at constructor. I had a look at it (https://github.com/playframework/play-scala/blob/master/src/play/db/anorm/Anorm.scala line 227). Indeed, it takes tableName at constructor, wrapped in an option. So you can do object User extends Magic[User](Some("users"))