# Play Scala Anorm "Magic[Country]().using("Countries")"

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

In looking at the docs for Play Scala Anorm, they show specifying a alternate table name as using this syntax:

```
object Country extends Magic[Country]().using("Countries")
```

When i try to use this i get:

```
Error raised is : ';' expected but '.' found.
```

What is the correct Scala syntax for this to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [object User extends Magic\[User\]().using("users") can not compiled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426593/object-user-extends-magicuser-usingusers-can-not-compiled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is an error in the example. You can do

```
val Country = new Magic[Country]().using("Countries")
```

but you certainly cannot do that with an object declaration
You can use another constructor of Magic

```
object Country extends Magic[Country](Some("Countries"))
```

(see [object User extends Magic[User]().using("users") can not compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6426593/754787))

Comment: thanks, that appears to work, sorry for the duplicate question, searching beforehand didn't give me the linked result.